# Sign up still successful even though username is taken

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a system where the user can't sign up if the username is already taken by others. However, this seems to not work as even though the username is taken, the sign up process is still completed.

I am doing this by retrieving every username from Firebase and running it through it see if the username entered by the user is already used. If it is, it should stop the sign up process and tell user to enter another username.

Code:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://heytest.firebaseio.com/")
        let usernamesRef = ref.child("users")

        usernamesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let con = snapshot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
            var usernamesArray = [String]()
            Array(con.keys).forEach {
                if let res = con[$0] , let username = res["username"] as? String {
                    usernamesArray.append(username)
                }
            }

            for storedUsername in usernamesArray {
                if storedUsername == self.usernameTextField.text! {
                    self.usernameVerified = false
                    self.usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                    self.usernameLabel.text = "USERNAME TAKEN"
                    self.usernameTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.red, thickness: 1.5)
                    return
                }
           }


        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


        print("TEST")
        self.usernameVerified = true
        print(self.usernameVerified)
        self.usernameTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.black, thickness: 1.5)
        self.usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        self.usernameLabel.text = "USERNAME"
```

On sign in button clicked:

```
@IBAction func onSignUp(_ sender: Any) {

    print("Sign Up pressed")
    isValidUsername(username: usernameTextField.text!)
    print("[SIGN UP] - Username: \(usernameVerified)")
    isValidEmail(email: emailTextField.text!)
    print("[SIGN UP] - Email: \(emailVerified)")
    isValidPassword(password: passwordTextField.text!)
    print("[SIGN UP] - Password: \(passwordVerified)")



    if passwordVerified && emailVerified && usernameVerified {

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (authResult, error) in
            if error != nil {
                self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
                self.errorLabel.text = error?.localizedDescription
                self.shake(viewToShake: self.errorLabel)
                return
            }

            guard let user = authResult?.user else {
                return
            }


            //Successfully Authenticated User
            let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://heytest.firebaseio.com/")
            let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(user.uid)
            let values = ["username": self.usernameTextField.text!, "email": self.emailTextField.text!, "games-played": "0"] 
            usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                if err != nil {
                    print(err!)
                    return
                }

                //Successfully registered user's data to database
                print("[SIGN UP] - Successfully Signed Up")
                self.errorLabel.alpha = 0
                self.present((self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController"))!, animated: false, completion: nil)


            })
        }

    } else {

        errorLabel.alpha = 1
        shake(viewToShake: errorLabel)
        print("Password/Email/Username verification not complete!")
        print("[SIGN UP] - Password: \(passwordVerified)")
        print("[SIGN UP] - Username: \(usernameVerified)")
        print("[SIGN UP] - Email: \(emailVerified)")

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be easier for you to see if any matches are thrown from firebase for a specific userName.

```
let reference = Database.database().reference()
reference.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: "yourNewUserName").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    // if there is data in the snapshot reject the registration else allow it
}
```

Otherwise you are downloading way too much data to the client. If you grow on users it will also take forever to download.

Comment: Thank you for your respond. I updated my code with implementation of code above. However, after clicking sign up and checking that the username is not taken, it still won't let u sign in until u click the sign in button again. I updated my question to include code that runs when sign in button is clicked. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any errors printed? or can you add some `print` test in the guard statement. Maybe it is returning because `authResult?.user` is nil

Comment: I did add some print statements. It seems like userVerified is false when it goes pass the if statement in the onSignUp code. After the if statement is run, userVerified switch to true. That is why the user have to click the sign up button again in order to create his/her acc.

Comment: Which `if` I don’t see any userVerified in the onSignUp? Where is each piece of the code being executed? Did you try to do it the way I suggested?

Comment: Sorry, I meant usernameVerified. The if is if passwordVerified && emailVerified && usernameVerified. I did try the way you suggested it.

Comment: Since my question is answered and this is a separate issue, I asked the question separately. It would be really appreciated if u can take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54270349/sign-up-button-must-be-clicked-twice-in-order-for-user-to-sign-up

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing this by retrieving every username from Firebase and running it through it see if the username entered by the user is already used.

IMHO this is not the right approach, the logic should be handled server side. Imagine if you have 1 million user this will never work.

Comment: what do you mean by this? usernameVerified is set to false if username is taken. Thanks for your help

Comment: my bad, I didn't see it, updating my answer