# Sign up button must be clicked twice in order for user to sign up

Tags: swift, firebase

When I sign up, for some reason I must click the sign up button twice before my account will be created. The first time I click it, an error label comes out even though email, username, and password is verified.

Here is a video: https://youtu.be/LTHElDXUWts

I think what is going on is that when I click sign up, passwordVerified and emailVerified is true but not usernameVerified. This is weird since usersnameVerified should be true since my username is not taken and is more than 3-15 characters. I added some print statement for debugging and saw that the usernameVerified is set to true AFTER the `if statement where it checks if everything is verified` is ran.

Here is my code:

```
 @IBAction func onSignUp(_ sender: Any) {

        print("Sign Up pressed")
        isValidUsername(username: usernameTextField.text!)
        print("[SIGN UP] - Username: \(usernameVerified)")
        isValidEmail(email: emailTextField.text!)
        print("[SIGN UP] - Email: \(emailVerified)")
        isValidPassword(password: passwordTextField.text!)
        print("[SIGN UP] - Password: \(passwordVerified)")



        if passwordVerified && emailVerified && usernameVerified {

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (authResult, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.errorLabel.alpha = 1
                    self.errorLabel.text = error?.localizedDescription
                    self.shake(viewToShake: self.errorLabel)
                    return
                }

                guard let user = authResult?.user else {
                    return
                }


                //Successfully Authenticated User
                let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://heytest.firebaseio.com/")
                let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(user.uid)
                let values = ["username": self.usernameTextField.text!, "email": self.emailTextField.text!, "games-played": "0"] 
                usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                    if err != nil {
                        print(err!)
                        return
                    }

                    //Successfully registered user's data to database
                    print("[SIGN UP] - Successfully Signed Up")
                    self.errorLabel.alpha = 0
                    self.present((self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController"))!, animated: false, completion: nil)


                })
            }

        } else {

            errorLabel.alpha = 1
            shake(viewToShake: errorLabel)
            print("Password/Email/Username verification not complete!")
            print("[SIGN UP] - Password: \(passwordVerified)")
            print("[SIGN UP] - Username: \(usernameVerified)")
            print("[SIGN UP] - Email: \(emailVerified)")

        }

    }

    //MARKUP: Validations/Verifications

    //Email Verification (Must follow correct email format: example@gmail.com)
    func isValidEmail(email: String) {

        let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
        var valid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: email)
        if valid {
            valid = !email.contains("Invalid email id")
        }

        if valid == false {


            emailLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            emailLabel.text = "EMAIL INVALID"
            emailTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.red, thickness: 1.5)

        } else {
            emailVerified = true
            emailTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.black, thickness: 1.5)
            emailLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            emailLabel.text = "EMAIL"
        }
    }


    //Password Verification (Must be greater than 8 digits
    func isValidPassword(password: String) {

        let passwordRegex = ".{8,}"
        var valid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluate(with: password)

        if valid {
            valid = !password.contains("Invalid password id")
        }

        if valid == false {


            passwordLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            passwordLabel.text = "PASSWORD MUST BE AT LEAST 8 DIGITS"
            passwordTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.red, thickness: 1.5)

        } else {
            passwordVerified = true
            passwordTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.black, thickness: 1.5)
            passwordLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
            passwordLabel.text = "PASSWORD"
        }
    }

    //Username Verification (Must be between 3-15 charaters w/ username not taken)
    func isValidUsername(username: String) {
        let usernameRegex = ".{3,15}"
        var valid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", usernameRegex).evaluate(with: username)

        if valid {
            valid = !username.contains("Invalid username id")
        }

        if valid == false {


            usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
            usernameLabel.text = "USERNAME MUST BE 3-15 CHARS"
            usernameTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.red, thickness: 1.5)

        } else {
            let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://heytest.firebaseio.com/")
            let usernamesRef = ref.child("users")
            usernamesRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: username).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
               // if there is data in the snapshot reject the registration else allow it

                if (snapshot.value! is NSNull) {

                    self.usernameVerified = true
                    print("[SIGN UP] - Username: \(self.usernameVerified)")
                    self.usernameTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.black, thickness: 1.5)
                    self.usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
                    self.usernameLabel.text = "USERNAME"

                } else {

                    self.usernameVerified = false
                    self.usernameTaken = true
                    self.usernameLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                    self.usernameLabel.text = "USERNAME TAKEN"
                    self.usernameTextField.layer.addBorder(edge: UIRectEdge.bottom, color: UIColor.red, thickness: 1.5)

                }

            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: Just eyeballing the code, it seems as though you might want to think about creating a separate class to handle the business logic of your view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I tried to add a few thing in you code but it is a bit difficult to read. You should really think about refactoring it.

Anyway, the problem is that you are never waiting for the result from the query to return, and you are just letting it run. Remember that Firebase is async. In your case I suggest you using a completion block for the `isValidUsername` method. Here is some code for you. Not sure if it will run as I cannot compile without creating all the UI components that you have. In the code below I removed a bunch of your code that does the UI changes if it is not verified. I also removed your verified variables since in this case you won't need them anymore. I commented all the code that I added so you can understand it easier.

```
@IBAction func onSignUp(_ sender: Any) {

        print("Sign Up pressed")
        guard let email = emailTextField.text else { return }
        guard let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }
        guard let userName = usernameTextField.text else { return }

        if isValidEmail(email: email) && isValidPassword(password: password) {
            // HERE YOU USE THE CLOSURE
            isValidUsername(username: userName) { (verified, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    // IF THERE IS ERROR RETURN
                    return
                }
                guard let verified = verified else { return }
                // IF IT IS A VALID USERNAME, PROCEED WITH SIGNUP
                if verified {
                    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (authResult, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            return
                        }

                        guard let user = authResult?.user else {
                            return
                        }

                        //Successfully Authenticated User
                        let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://heytest.firebaseio.com/")
                        let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(user.uid)
                        let values = ["username": self.usernameTextField.text!, "email": self.emailTextField.text!, "games-played": "0"]
                        usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
                            if err != nil {
                                print(err!)
                                return
                            }

                            //Successfully registered user's data to database
                            print("[SIGN UP] - Successfully Signed Up")
                            self.present((self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController"))!, animated: false, completion: nil)


                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {

        }

    }

    //MARKUP: Validations/Verifications
    //Email Verification (Must follow correct email format: example@gmail.com)
    func isValidEmail(email: String) -> Bool {

        let emailRegex = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
        var valid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex).evaluate(with: email)
        if valid {
            valid = !email.contains("Invalid email id")
        }

        if valid == false {

            return false

        } else {

            return true
        }
    }


    //Password Verification (Must be greater than 8 digits
    func isValidPassword(password: String) -> Bool {

        let passwordRegex = ".{8,}"
        var valid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", passwordRegex).evaluate(with: password)

        if valid {
            valid = !password.contains("Invalid password id")
        }

        if valid == false {

            return false

        } else {

            return true
        }
    }

    //Username Verification (Must be between 3-15 charaters w/ username not taken)
    // HERE IS A CLOSURE
    typealias validateClosure = (Bool?, Error?) -> Void
    func isValidUsername(username: String, completion: @escaping validateClosure) {
        let usernameRegex = ".{3,15}"
        var valid = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", usernameRegex).evaluate(with: username)

        if valid {
            valid = !username.contains("Invalid username id")
        }

        if valid == false {

        } else {
            let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://heytest.firebaseio.com/")
            let usernamesRef = ref.child("users")
            usernamesRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: username).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                // if there is data in the snapshot reject the registration else allow it

                if (snapshot.value! is NSNull) {
                    // RETURN TRUE IF VERIFIED
                    completion(true, nil)

                } else {
                    // RETURN FALSE IF NOT VARIFIED
                    completion(false, nil)

                }

            }) { (error) in
                // RETURN FALSE AND THE ERROR
                completion(false, error)
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }
    }
```

Hope it helps. And please really give it some thought about moving all the code that does network calls and business logic to another class and away of the viewController. It will make your life much easier later.